# How to Intercept Outbound WCF Service Calls from a .NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

The .NET web applications we build all integrate with a third party application through a WCF service. Every time a page loads a number of WCF service calls are made to retrieve data that are used to populate some user controls.

Through AppDynamics I can tell that there could be up to 8 WCF calls to load a given page. AppDynamics tells us that the WCF calls cost up to 85% of the load time. This is a serious impact on developer productivity.

Is there a way to intercept all the outbound WCF calls from our .NET web application and stub them with fake data so that pages will not break and load faster? The pages do not need these data to run in development environment.

Thanks for your input!

John

Answer (score 0):

Use Dependency Injection instead of creating the actual WCF endpoints and passing them around. Then mocking them up is trivial. You would then use the interface and let DI take care of the rest!

Comment: Thanks @SledgeHammer for your reply. Your reply made me realize that I need to add a bit clarification to my question. What I need to add is: the code that makes the integration WCF service calls is from the vendor of the WCF service and is provided as DLLs. As you can see that we have no controls over the calls they make.

Comment: @John Then you would need to wrap the DLL in an interface and use DI at that level. The real interface implementation would just call the DLL methods as light weight pass-through while the dev implementation would just be empty methods.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I will try it out and let you know how it goes.